# fundamental theorem of calculus 2

Tags: calculus, integration

Differentiate the following equation with respect to $x$:

$$8 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt = 2 x^{1/2}$$

Hence, find a function $f(x)$ and real number $a$  such that the above equation is true for all $x>0$.

Comment: Please let us know what your thoughts are about this problem, and what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus (assuming $a>0$),
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
so $f(x)=x^{3/2}$. For the second part,
$$
\int_a^x\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,dt=2\sqrt{x}-8
$$
and so $2\sqrt{a}-8=0$, by letting $x=a$.

Comment: i dont understand the part where 2a^1/2 - 8 = 0, what is the theorem u used to get this form ?

Comment: If equality must hold for every $x$, it should in particular for $a$. The integral in the left-hand side is then $\int_a^a \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,dt=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that

$$\displaystyle 8 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt = 2 x^{1/2}$$

differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ yields

$$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left[8 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt\right] = \frac{d}{dx}\left[2x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]$$

$$\displaystyle 0+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x)-\frac{f(a)}{a^2}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(a) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Rightarrow f(x) = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Plugging in $f(x) = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$, we get $$\displaystyle 8 + \int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt = 2 x^{1/2}$$

Finally, let $x=a$. This results in

$$\displaystyle 8+\int_a^a \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt = 2 a^{1/2}$$

Therefore $2\sqrt{a} = 8\Rightarrow \sqrt{a} = 4\Rightarrow a = 16$

Answer (score 0):

1. Letting $x=a$, we have
   $$8 + \int_a^a \frac{f(t)}{t^2}\, dt = 2 a^{1/2},$$ hence $a=16$.
2. Assuming by educated guess that $f(t)=\beta t^\alpha$,

$$\int \beta t^{\alpha-2}dt=\beta\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1}=2x^{1/2},$$i.e. $$\alpha=\frac32,\beta=1,f(x)=x^{3/2}.$$

---

Check:
$$8+\int_{16}^x\frac{x^{3/2}}{x^2}dx=8+\int_{16}^x\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=8+\left.2\sqrt x\right|_{16}^x=2x^{1/2}.$$